# simulate touch events on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, touch-event

I want to simulate a touch event on my own application.
Although this question has been asked before, I would like to simulate touch on my own application.

When I use these codes, my application crashes. I don't know where the problem is.
MainActivity:
https://justpaste.it/7g7ct

And MyService:
https://justpaste.it/2uury

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myapplicationdffghgh;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.nio.file.Path;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, GestureDescription.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);

        GestureDescription.createClick(581,1044);


    }




   


}
```

Comment: put your code in here, it will be nicely colored and readable. and also put exception stacktrace from logcat

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onTouchEvent method of View, and create a MotionEvent with the coordinates you need.

```
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
int metaState = 0;
MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
    downTime, 
    eventTime, 
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
    x, 
    y, 
    metaState
);

view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

Comment: view is red line, can you help me?